# Overwrite ListBoxitem?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF and I have this ListBox which I want to instantiate with a specific ListBoxItem, so the user knows what to do with the ListBox.

```
 <ListBox Name="DbListBox"
             Grid.Column="3"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Height="246"
             Margin="0,99,0,0"
             Grid.Row="1"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Width="211"
             SelectionMode="Single"
             SelectedItem="{Binding Path=selectedDB,Mode=TwoWay}" 
             AllowDrop="True"
             Drop="DbListBox_Drop">
        <ListBoxItem Name="ListBoxItem" FontStyle="Italic">Drag .db file here or add below</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

Then I have some code which adds a collection of items to the ItemsSource of this ListBox, but I can't do that since the ItemsSource is not empty

```
DbListBox.ItemsSource = DbCollection;
```

My question is, how can I start up the ListBox with the item inserted first, and then when DbCollection is added to it, it simply overwrites the first ListBoxItem?

Answer (score 0):

When using WPF properly, we'd normally have something like this, where a collection property would be data bound to the `ListBox.ItemsSource` property:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollectionProperty}" />
```

Once we have this XAML, we don't need to touch the `ListBox` again, as we can add or remove items *from the data bound collection* and they will magically appear (or disappear) from the `ListBox`:

```
SomeCollectionProperty.Add(new SomeDataType());
SomeCollectionProperty.Remove(someItemFromCollection);
```

The `SomeDataType` used here is up to you... it depends on what you want to display in your items. If it was just a plain `string` for example, then you could simply do this to add your initial item into the collection:

```
SomeCollectionProperty.Add("Drag .db file here or add below");
```

If you wanted to make that item look different to the others then you'd need to data bind a custom class that has a `Text` property and `FontStyle` property for example. You could data bind these properties in a `DataTemplate` to design each item to be exactly as you want it. However, that's a completely different question.

To find out more about these things, you can read the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: Neat. I've added ItemsSource="{Binding DbListProperty}" to the ListBox now, but I can't seem to find it from my MainWindow.xaml.cs file?

Comment: Read the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.